# Creating boundaries for Camera with with mouse drag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

I've made an orthographic camera that is moving by dragging a mouse but can't understand how to create a boundaries for it. It seems that I have to use Mathf.Clamp but can't find out how.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cameraTransform;

    public float movementSpeed;
    public float movementTime;

    public Vector3 newPosition;

    public Vector3 dragStartPosition;
    public Vector3 dragCurrentPosition;

    public Camera cam;
    public float maxZoom = 5;
    public float minZoom = 20;
    public float sensitivity = 1;
    public float speed = 30;
    float targetZoom;

    public float minX = 100;
    public float maxX = 120;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        newPosition = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        HandleMouseInput();
        HandleMovementInput();

        {
            targetZoom -= Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * sensitivity;
            targetZoom = Mathf.Clamp(targetZoom, maxZoom, minZoom);
            float newSize = Mathf.MoveTowards(cam.orthographicSize, targetZoom, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            cam.orthographicSize = newSize;
        }
    }

    void HandleMouseInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            float entry;

            if (plane.Raycast(ray, out entry))
            {
                dragStartPosition = ray.GetPoint(entry);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            float entry;

            if (plane.Raycast(ray, out entry))
            {
                dragCurrentPosition = ray.GetPoint(entry);

                newPosition = transform.position + dragStartPosition - dragCurrentPosition;
            }
        }

        newPosition = Mathf.Clamp(minX, minX);
    }

    void HandleMovementInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.forward * movementSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.forward * -movementSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.right * movementSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            newPosition += (transform.right * -movementSpeed);
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, Time.deltaTime * movementTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've shared a lot of code, but is there any way you can simplify it down to a [mcve]?  Where exactly is the problem -- is it in `Update()`?  If so, what is your current implementation doing wrong?  The more you share about where you are currently stuck, the more likely we are to be able to help you resolve your problem.  See: [ask].

Comment: Thank you for a response. Problem is in a void HandleMouseInput.  Ive used newPosition = Mathf.Clamp(minX, minX); created two float public float minX and max.  Mouse drag stopped working

Answer (score 0):

```
newPosition = Mathf.Clamp(minX, minX);
```

You can't clamp with only two parameters .. you need a current, a min and a max value .. And you can't just convert a `float` which is what `Mathf.Clamp` returns  into a `Vector3` (3 floats)

I think what you meant was rather something like e.g.

```
newPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(newPosition.x, minX, maxX);
```

However, right after that in `HandleMovementInput` you overwrite it anyway so you might want to change the moment when you are clamping and rather do it right before applying the new position.